# Using a stack to do an infix to postfix

Tags: c, stack, infix-notation

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "stack.h"

#define MAX_EQU_LEN 100

static int prec(char operator)
{
    switch (operator)
    {
        case '*':
            return 5;
        case '/':
            return 4;
        case '%':
            return 3;
        case '+':
            return 2;
        case '-':
            return 1;
        default:
            break;
    }

    return 0;
}

static int isNumeric(char* num)
{
    if(atoi(num) == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
            return 1;
}

char* infix_to_postfix(char* infix)
{
    char* postfix = malloc(MAX_EQU_LEN);
    stack* s = create_stack();
    s->size = strlen(infix);
    node* tempPtr = s->stack;
    unsigned int i;
    char symbol,next;
    char temp[2] = {0};

    for(i = 0; i < s->size ; i++)
    {
        symbol = *((infix + i));
        temp[0] = symbol;
        tempPtr = s->stack;
        if(isNumeric(temp) != 1)
        {
            strcat(postfix, temp);
        }
        else if(symbol == '(')
        {
            push(s, symbol);
        }
        else if(symbol == ')')
        {
            while(s->size != 0 && top(s) != '(')
            {
                next = tempPtr->data;
                temp[0] = next;
                pop(s);
                strcat(postfix, temp);
                tempPtr = s->stack;
                if(tempPtr->data == '(')
                {
                    pop(s);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            while(s->size != 0 && prec(top(s)) > prec(symbol))
            {
                next = tempPtr->data;
                temp[0] = next;
                pop(s);
                strcat(postfix,temp);
                push(s,next);
            }
        }
        while(s->size != 0)
        {
            next = tempPtr->data;
            temp[0] = next;
            pop(s);
            strcat(postfix, temp);
        }
    }
    return postfix;

}

int evaluate_postfix(char* postfix) {

    //For each token in the string
        int i,result;
        int right, left;
        char ch;
        stack* s = create_stack();
        node* tempPtr = s->stack;

        for(i=0; i < strlen(postfix); i++){
            //if the token is numeric
            ch = postfix[i];
            if(isNumeric(&ch)){
                //convert it to an integer and push it onto the stack
                atoi(&ch);
                push(s, ch);
            }
            else
            {
                pop(&s[0]);
                pop(&s[1]);
                //apply the operation:
                //result = left op right
                       switch(ch)
                       {
                           case '+': push(&s[i],right + left);
                                     break;
                           case '-': push(&s[i],right - left);
                                     break;
                           case '*': push(&s[i],right * left);
                                     break;
                           case '/': push(&s[i],right / left);
                                     break;
                       }
                }
        }
        tempPtr = s->stack;
        //return the result from the stack
        return(tempPtr->data);

}
```

This code is part of a bigger program that is designed to convert simple math from infix to postfix and then evaluate it. This will be aided by a stack to hold the numbers and symbols. However when I run the program it seg faults and all the debugger says is that it is in the infix_to_postfix function and I cannot figure out what part of the code makes it seg fault.

Comment: The debugger can tell you exactly which line is causing the segfault. It can also show you the value of the variables at that time.  Determine which pointer is bad, then work your way backwards to determine how it got that bad value. This is standard debugging work, which all C programmers should eventually be very familiar with.

Comment: The gdb debugger just said Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000400a87 in infix_to_postfix ()
(gdb)

Comment: Use gdb's backtrace (`bt`) command after the segfault.  Use the `frame` command to examine the context of the various levels of the resulting call tree.  If you have not compiled with debugging symbols available (`-g` option in GCC), then recompiling with them will yield a program that gdb can explain to you more clearly.

Comment: I found out the following 
  tempPtr node * NULL 0x0000000000000000
temp char [2]  
[0] char '\xcf' '
[1] char '\0' '\0'
postfix char * 0x100105420 
s stack * 0x100105490 
next char '\0'

Also the seg fault occurred in this while loop
while(s->size != 0 && top(s) != '(')
            {
                next = tempPtr->data;
                temp[0] = next;
                pop(s);
                strcat(postfix, temp);
                tempPtr = s->stack;
                if(tempPtr->data == '(')
                {
                    pop(s);
                }
            }